# AndEngine and rotate object

Tags: android, andengine

There is something what I can use to rotate object without ending? I want start game and start rotate sprite with some speed but I don't want to end rotate. There is any way to use: `new RotationModifier(20f, 0, 360)`, but with no end of rotation? Or there is any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use LoopEntityModifier, something like (haven't tried it out):

```
LoopEntityModifier EntityModifier = new LoopEntityModifier(
                                        new RotationModifier(1,0,360));
```